# Playwright not waiting for elements to be visible

Tags: svelte, playwright

I'm trying to write a "hello world" test using Playwright to start testing my Svelte app.  The app shows a loading screen for about two seconds, then shows the app itself, which shows some data in a table.  I want to simply detect that there is a table on the screen.

To get past the loading screen, I'm using the waitFor() method, but it keeps timing out after about two seconds no matter what I put for the timeout value in the Playwright config.  I even put it to 100000ms and it still times out after about two seconds (same amount of time as the loading screen is on the screen).  The error that appears is that the 100000ms timeout has been exceeded, which obviously isn't true.  I even tried the page.slow() option, but then it just says I've exceeded the 300000ms timeout.

Here's the test I'm trying to get to work.  Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
test('The table is present after the loading screen disappears', async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto('localhost:3000');
    const tbl = await page.locator('table');
    await tbl.waitFor();
    await expect(tbl.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

Here's what the relevant part of my playwright.config.ts look like:

```
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './e2e',
  /* Maximum time one test can run for. */
  timeout: 100 * 1000,
  expect: {
    /**
     * Maximum time expect() should wait for the condition to be met.
     * For example in `await expect(locator).toHaveText();`
     */
    timeout: 500000000
  },
```

Here's the error:
[image]

Comment: Try removing the `await` before `page.locator('table')` as that does not return a promise.  That has the potential to cause issues.

Comment: @AJG `await`ing a value that’s not a Promise just silently wraps the value in a promise resolved to the value, thus will give the value just the same, and doesn’t affect any functionality, albeit redundant.

Comment: @David I feel like I ran into that quirkiness as well where it gives an error like that when it’s not the true culprit. I believe it actually may be due to an unhandled promise, basically the promise is still being resolved when the test ends, and maybe causes an issue with the context trying to close. Not sure about the context close piece, but if I’m right on the cause/issue, `count()` returns a promise, which isn’t being awaited nor is expect told to wait and unwrap it so it doesn’t wait, just checking if the promise is greater than 0. You need .resolves, like so: (Continued in next comment

Comment: `await expect(tbl.count()).resolves.toBeGreaterThan(0);
});` See https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#resolves. Not 100% confident that’s causing what you’re seeing, so let me know and if so I’ll post an actual answer. That will definitely be needed for the test to work as you intended though, just not sure if it’s causing the error you’re seeing. (Though it would explain why it happens right after loading finishes, since the expect then immediately happens and fails, ending the test)

Comment: Thank you @DavidR, that did indeed cause the test to pass.  I've also marked the answer below as correct, because I think that code provided is the way this should be done if possible, rather than manually resolving promises.  Though I didn't know about .resolve, and I imagine it is going to be extremely useful, thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: @David awesome! I admit, I was half asleep while writing, and for your use case where the goal what asserting/expecting it to be visible, that would be my recommended approach too. There are still times to use waitFor instead, but not when it’s part of the assertion you’re trying to make since the indicated assertions are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell, why your script isn't working, without really debugging it. I recommend running `npx playwright test --debug` or the VS Code extension to have a detailed look.

Side note: as @AJG pointed out, locators are lazy and don't need to be awaited. They're only evaluated when you're using them with e.g. `expect`.

That said, for the use case of an element being visible, you should rely on [Playwright's web-first assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions).

Playwright has auto-waiting built-in so that you can usually avoid manual `waitFor` statements. E.g. [`await expect(locator).toBeVisible()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible) waits and retries until the condition is met (or it times out).

For your case (and assuming that there's only one `table` on the page), the following should do the trick:

```
test('The table is present after the loading screen disappears', async ({page}) => {
    // wait for the 'load' event
    // which probably doesn't help in your case
    await page.goto('localhost:3000');
    const tbl = page.locator('table');
    // waits until `tbl` becomes visible
    // timeout in your case is `500000000`
    await expect(tbl).toBeVisible();
});
```

Comment: The provided code does solve the issue, thank you.  Just a quick note: the recommendation to use --debug won't be helpful for people facing an issue like the one I was facing, because the test always passed in --debug mode.  When the debugger came up, it would allow enough time for the loading screen to go away, and the table was always found.

Comment: Well. happy it's resolved. :)